# Pegar o texto da Label somente se existir Label

Tags: javascript, jquery

Segue o HTML:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="etapa3">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="row informativo">
            <!-- Aqui vai ser inserida a tabela via Jquery -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <label class="control-label">Capital de Giro:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control money" name="txt_capitalGiro">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 "> 
            <button type="button" data-aprovacao="Aprovado" class="btn btn-primary btn-block aprovado">Aprovado</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 "> 
            <button type="button" data-aprovacao="Reprovado" class="btn btn-primary btn-block reprovado">Reprovado</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 "> 
            <button type="button" data-aprovacao="Revisar" class="btn btn-primary btn-block revisar">Revisar</button>
        </div>
        <input name="reg_etapa3" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <div class="row div-Invisivel">
        <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">Justificativa:</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="just_3" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">Observações:</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="txtArea_observacaoEtapa3" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7"> 
            <label class="control-label">Responsável:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="colab_3" name="colab_3">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
            <label class="control-label">Data:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data_3" name="data_3">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <label class="control-label">Hora:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hora_3" name="hora_3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  <!-- Fecha Etapa 03 -->
```

Eu gostaria de pegar todos os textos das labels dentro dos `.form-group`.
Segue o código:

```
$("#etapa3").find(".form-group").not('.well .form-group').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find("label").text());
});
```

Porém o script tentar pegar o texto de uma label nos botões e o console.log devolve espaço em branco. Segue foto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei o porque isso acontece. Alguém saberia me explicar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque ao imprimir o log com a linha `console.log($(this).find("label").text());` ele executa na seguinte sequencia:

1. `$(this)` -> Pega o elemento atual o `each`
2. `.find("label")` -> procura todas tags `label` descendentes do retorno anterior
3. `.text()` -> Pega o texto das tags `labes` retornadas
4. console.log(...) -> Envia para o log o retorno do `text()`

Ou seja, no passo 2, se ele não encontrar a tag `label` ele vai procurar o texto e não vai ter nada, retornando nada para o `console.log`, que por sua vez recebe um valor vazio e imprime um valor vazio.

Para resolver isso, você precisa verificar antes se exite algum label no each, segue abaixo um exemplo:

```js
$("#etapa3").find(".form-group").not('.well .form-group').each(function(){
    if($(this).find("label").length > 0) {
      console.log($(this).find("label").text());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane" id="etapa3">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="row informativo">
                <!-- Aqui vai ser inserida a tabela via Jquery -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <label class="control-label">Capital de Giro:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control money" name="txt_capitalGiro">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 "> 
                <button type="button" data-aprovacao="Aprovado" class="btn btn-primary btn-block aprovado">Aprovado</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 "> 
                <button type="button" data-aprovacao="Reprovado" class="btn btn-primary btn-block reprovado">Reprovado</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 "> 
                <button type="button" data-aprovacao="Revisar" class="btn btn-primary btn-block revisar">Revisar</button>
            </div>
            <input name="reg_etapa3" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="row div-Invisivel">
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-heading">Justificativa:</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="just_3" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">Observações:</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="txtArea_observacaoEtapa3" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7"> 
                <label class="control-label">Responsável:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="colab_3" name="colab_3">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
                <label class="control-label">Data:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data_3" name="data_3">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <label class="control-label">Hora:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hora_3" name="hora_3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- Fecha Etapa 03 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```js
$("#etapa3").find(".form-group").not('.well .form-group').each(function(){
    if ($(this).find("label").text() != ""){
       console.log($(this).find("label").text());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane" id="etapa3">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="row informativo">
                <!-- Aqui vai ser inserida a tabela via Jquery -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <label class="control-label">Capital de Giro:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control money" name="txt_capitalGiro">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 "> 
                <button type="button" data-aprovacao="Aprovado" class="btn btn-primary btn-block aprovado">Aprovado</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 "> 
                <button type="button" data-aprovacao="Reprovado" class="btn btn-primary btn-block reprovado">Reprovado</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 "> 
                <button type="button" data-aprovacao="Revisar" class="btn btn-primary btn-block revisar">Revisar</button>
            </div>
            <input name="reg_etapa3" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="row div-Invisivel">
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-heading">Justificativa:</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="just_3" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">Observações:</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="txtArea_observacaoEtapa3" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7"> 
                <label class="control-label">Responsável:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="colab_3" name="colab_3">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
                <label class="control-label">Data:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data_3" name="data_3">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <label class="control-label">Hora:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hora_3" name="hora_3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- Fecha Etapa 03 -->
```

Dessa forma ele primeiro verifica se o o `label` é vazio e só imprime se o mesmo não for vazio.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar o seletor do jQuery `.find("label:not(:empty)")` e assim fica já filtrado.

```js
$("#etapa3").find(".form-group").not('.well .form-group').find("label:not(:empty)").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane" id="etapa3">
  <div class="well">
    <div class="row informativo">
      <!-- Aqui vai ser inserida a tabela via Jquery -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <label class="control-label">Capital de Giro:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control money" name="txt_capitalGiro">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ">
      <button type="button" data-aprovacao="Aprovado" class="btn btn-primary btn-block aprovado">Aprovado</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ">
      <button type="button" data-aprovacao="Reprovado" class="btn btn-primary btn-block reprovado">Reprovado</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ">
      <button type="button" data-aprovacao="Revisar" class="btn btn-primary btn-block revisar">Revisar</button>
    </div>
    <input name="reg_etapa3" type="hidden">
  </div>
  <div class="row div-Invisivel">
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">Justificativa:</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="just_3" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">Observações:</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="txtArea_observacaoEtapa3" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
      <label class="control-label">Responsável:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="colab_3" name="colab_3">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
      <label class="control-label">Data:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data_3" name="data_3">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <label class="control-label">Hora:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hora_3" name="hora_3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```